# How to get first value of array using Volley in android

Tags: android, android-volley

How to get first value of array using Volley in android? this method is successfully for me to get all value from array, but i just want to get first value only.

```
private void getValue(PriceModel priceModel, final ViewHolderPrice holder) {

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            ServerApi.URL + priceModel.get_id(),
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(!response.isEmpty()) {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();

                        PriceModel[] priceModels = gson.fromJson(response, PriceModel[].class); for(PriceModel price: priceModels)  holder.tvPrice.setText(variantModels.getPrice());

                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, error.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
    );
    Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext).add(request);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried priceModels[0] ?

Comment: @MagnusW owh, i already get it. thanks